# How do I  send crash report to Web service when application gets crashed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

As per client requirement i want  to send crash Report when App get crash.
How its possible to send crash report without crashing the app.Is there any link or document for this.

Please suggest me the way to do this.otherwise post me code for this.

Thank you.

Comment: How would you get crash report without the Crash !!! ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send your crash report when user start the application after the crash.

Download the [crashManagetLib](https://github.com/kstenerud/Crash-Manager) to read crash report.

You can write your crash reading code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like: -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    [self checkCrash];
}

// To check Crash and attach the crash file to Email
- (void) checkChrash
{
    //code for the application crash report.
    NSFileManager *file = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *errorReportPath = [[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"crash_report.plcrash"] retain];

    //Call Crash Manager if apps is crashed
    [[CrashManager sharedInstance] manageCrashes];
    [[CrashManager sharedInstance] setCrashDelegate:self selector:@selector(notifyException:stackTrace:)];

    //Mail Dialog is display if apps is crashed
    NSString* errorReport = [CrashManager sharedInstance].errorReport;

    if ([file fileExistsAtPath:errorReportPath]) 
    {
        if(nil != errorReport)
        {           
            // log out from facebook.
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"TOKEN"];

            NSString *crashResponce = [BKAPIClient sendCrashReportByMethod:aCrashReport WithErrorLog:errorReport];
            NSLog(@"%@",crashResponce);
            if ([crashResponce isEqualToString:@"True"])
            {
                NSLog(@"Crash Report has been sent !");
            }

            [file removeItemAtPath:errorReportPath error:nil];          
        }
    }

    [errorReportPath release];  
}

// For stack trace of crash
- (void) notifyException:(NSException*) exception stackTrace:(NSArray*)stackTrace
{
    // Oh no!  We crashed!
    // Time to output some stuff to the console.

    // Note: Any EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes (such as accessing a deallocated object) will
    // cause the app to close stdout, so you won't see this trace in such a case.

    NSLog(@"Exception:\n%@\n", exception);

    NSLog(@"Full Trace:\n%@\n", [[StackTracer sharedInstance] printableTrace:stackTrace]);

    NSArray* intelligentTrace = [[StackTracer sharedInstance] intelligentTrace:stackTrace];
    NSLog(@"Condensed Intelligent Trace:\n%@", [[StackTracer sharedInstance] condensedPrintableTrace:intelligentTrace]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving that snippet. i have done as per your given code. Now am facing BKAPIClient use of undeclared error. What is BKAPIClient.? how to resolve this? @Maulik

Comment: @AsokanR: Hi, its just a class that calls web service in my case. You just need to write code to call your specific web service. Thats it !